# jQuery .data() function works when selector targets 1 element, but not when targetting multiple and iterating over them

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to read the data value of each checkbox that is checked, to do this I have the following code:

```
var jobjChk = $("input:checkbox[name=resourceSelect]:checked");
jobjChk.each(function () {
    receivers[receivers.length] = this.data("data-email");
});
```

Now when only one checkbox is checked, and I use this.data, the code works as expected. When I use the code above and have multiple checkboxes selected, "I get Object doesn't support property or method 'data'". But both should be jquery objects (and supporting .data())?

Comment: use $(this).data(), rather than this.data()

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are incorrect. This statement:

> But both should be jquery objects (and supporting .data())?

is incorrect. The `this` inside of the `.each()` callback is the actual DOM element, it's *not* a jQuery object. If you want to use jQuery functions you need to create a new jQuery object containing that single element:

```
jobjChk.each(function () {
    receivers[receivers.length] = $(this).data("data-email");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Update to this line:

```
 receivers[receivers.length] = $(this).data("data-email");
```

or if your checkbox is having attr like this `data-email="abc@xyz.com"` then you can use this:

```
 receivers[receivers.length] = $(this).data("email");
```

---

#### See:

In your code `this` belongs to the dom node in your document it is not a jQuery object wrapped with like this `$(this)` or `jQuery(this)`.

so
`this` belongs to dom node.
`$(this)` is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/99T5P/

Firstly change the line

```
receivers[receivers.length] = this.data("data-email");
```

to

```
receivers[receivers.length] = $(this).data("data-email");
```

Next, while reading data attributes you should use something like this `$(this).data("email")` instead of this `$(this).data("data-email")` and your HTML should be like below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="resourceSelect" value="dog" data-email="a@a.com" />I have a dog
```